# Correct Symfony-doctrine inheritance mapping

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I recently started using Symfony2-Doctrine2. I'm not getting how to save data in [inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

**My requirements:**

For learning exercise:

- I'm making a library application for testing (Requirements might not be practical).
- At high level, library may contain many different type of items like books, articles, manuals as example for now.
- They have some common fields like name, publish year etc and some item specific details like book has IDBN, publisher; Manual have company, product.
- Again to make problem little more complex, there is another 'item_content' table to have some description in different language.

To quickly visualize, I've following structure:

[image]

I achieved above structure as per doctrine docs for [inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) & [Bidirectional one to many relation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

**My Question**: How to save data using Symfony2 (I've proper routing/actions running, just need code to write in controller or better in repository). While saving data (say for manual) I want to save data in Item, Manual and ItemContect table but getting confused due to `discr` field in database. I didn't find code for saving data in above structure. **I don't need full code, just few hints will be sufficient.** My Item class is as follow (Other classes have proper inverse as mentioned in doctrine docs):

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="item")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\LibraryBundle\Entity\ItemRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"book" = "Book", "manual" = "Manual", "article" =  "Article"})
 */
class Item
{
    //...

    /**
     *  For joining with ItemContent
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ItemContent", mappedBy="item")
     **/
    private $itemContents; 

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->itemContents = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discriminator field will be automatically filled by Doctrine

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$item = new Manual(); // discr field = "manual"
$itemContent = new ItemContent();

$item->addItemContent($itemContent);
$itemContent->setItem($item);

$em->persist($item);
$em->persist($itemContent);
$em->flush();
```

Is that the answer you're waiting ?

Comment: Thanks @VBee Ahh yes, my bad. Didn't consider `$item = new Manual();` I was creating separate objects for Item and Manual.
But this raised another doubt, I don't want to write that code in controller but repository. So where `$item = new Manual();` belongs? ItemRepository or ManualRepository.

Comment: ManualRepository doesn't exist, and the best practice is to create a custom entity manager (like https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php). I advise you to put this logic in your controller in a first time.

Comment: sorry, you can create ManualRepository, but my advise is the same, use repositories for fetching data only.